# EPSON T20iii ePOS JavaScript SDK timeout issue (possible SSL issue)

Tags: javascript, ssl, sdk, epson, epos

I have just started using EPSON JavaScript SDK for printing over LAN, and for the most part, it works very well.

I have only one issue that is bugging me. After a period of time, approximately few days apart, I get a timeout error, and printer won't print any more.

I quickly realized that I need to login to the printer config page, which gives me a untrusted SSL warning, and after I login, printer starts working properly.

That gave me idea that self-signed certificates could be the issue. I have tries setting Automatic Redirect HTTP to HTTPS to disable, and accessing the printer over http instead of https, but to no avail. It seems that EPSON regenerates those certificates periodically.

I still need to login to printer once in a while to continue printing.

I hope somebody has a solution for this issue or maybe just to point me in the right direction.

Regards,

Comment: Did it work ? I have a similar problem. I try to join the printer in local from a domain name in https. I've got an error "http://192.168.1.118:8008/socket.io/1/?t=1630937369238'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `ePosDev.connect(ip,port,cbFunction)`, choose port 8008 to send the information via HTTP, otherwise it will use HTTPS and you will be warned with ERR_CERTIFICATE.

Note that using port 8008 sends the data without encryption.